# Alternatives to DADiSP?

Tags: data-visualization, data-analysis

I have been reviewing DADiSP 6.5 for use in a large project.  This software looks very promising however, I would like to look at alternatives software as well.Some of the concerns on DADiSP are:

- The user interface is somewhat dated - since Windows 10 is coming out, this has raised concerns.  Having to run an older version of Windows in a virtual machine in order to run an application will eliminate the software as a candidate.

  - Reviews are very positive - but once again, dated.

What are some alternatives to DADiSP that support large data streams (on the order of 50 to 100 GB)?

Answer (score 1):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) with [Python](http://python.org) & [iPython](http://ipython.org/) is more than powerful enough to do that size data stream, is free, open source, cross platform and you can use a web interface. Plus you can directly access databases, the web, etc., as your data sources.

If you specifically like the spreadsheet like interface it may also be worth looking at [pyspread](http://manns.github.io/pyspread/download.html).